# nth:child selector - different parrents

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

So i've always had some misunderstanding with nth child and selectors.
I have been trying to figure it out but after searching I could not find the answer.

This is my css

```
p.hi:nth-of-type(1) {
     color: blue;
}
```

This is my html

```
<div class"head">
    <p class="hi">This is some text.</p>
</div>

<div class"head">
    <p class="hi">This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

Currently this css is applying the color blue to both paragraphs. How do I make it only add it to the first? I know that if i put them both in the same div it works but what if it is nested several times. How do i select only one?

Take a look at this fiddle. 
http://jsfiddle.net/x9jkq0x3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9jkq0x3/1/)

```css
div:nth-of-type(1) p.hi {
    color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="head">
    <p class="hi">This is some text.</p>
</div>

<div class="head">
    <p class="hi">This is some text.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `first-child` to class head instead class hi
this is the example [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x9jkq0x3/3/)

Comment: hm, would have never thought about doing that. thanks